# Regarding Kirchoff's Loop Law

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electrical-resistance, voltage, electronics

I heard that the reason Kirchoff's Loop Law (also called Voltage Law) works is because of the conservation of energy, or more precisely, as the electromagnetic field is a conservative field, the potentials we deal with in the circuit are conservative, and therefore the work done around a loop must be zero - which translates to the sum of the voltage drop across a given circuit loop to be zero.

My question is that when current flows through the circuit (say, with resistors), there will be some heat loss due to the joule heating effect, and therefore we really cannot use the conservation of energy as an explanation behind why Kirchoff's Loop Law works.

Am I going wrong anywhere? With the above reasoning, shouldn't Kirchoff's Loop Law be wrong, or at best, give barely correct answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Energy is conserved. To state it simply, the loss of electrical potential energy that the charge acquires from, say, a battery equals the increase in kinetic energy of molecules of the resistors due to collisions with the electrons, raising the temperature of the resistors.

Then the temperature difference between the resistors and the environment results in heat transfer from the resistors to the environment.

Hope this helps.